Is there a log-concave distribution not spherical symmetric s.t $ \langle X, \theta \rangle$ is almost normal for all directions $\theta$?
Klartag's results indicate that for a log-concave isotropic random vector, with high probability over $\theta$, $\langle X, \theta \rangle$ is close to a normal distribution.
It is known that for the ball of radius $\sqrt{n+2}$, this holds for any $\theta$. Moreover, a result by Meckes in 2005 (Theorem 7 : https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0505618) states that for all spherical symmetric distributions, $\langle X, \theta \rangle$ is nearly Gaussian in high dimensions. My question is: Does there exist a log-concave distribution that is not spherical symmetric such that $\langle X, \theta \rangle$ is close to a normal distribution for all $\theta$?
